# One port over wifi, other use lan

Tags: wireless, lan, port-forwarding

I Am working in a place where my imap for e-mail (using thunderbird) is only open over wifi. The rest will mostly work only over wired (and is quicker  anyway).
So what is the best option to use my mail (lets say the imap port for smtp 993 and 465) over the wifi and all the others over wired, when both wifi and wired connected.
And only for this location by the way (so probably a batch to undo it and redo it).
Using ubuntu 14.04 desktop (on laptop).

Answer (score 0):

Problem can be solved with adding extra routes based on destination.

From terminal

```
sudo ip route add ip_address_mail_server dev wlan0
```

This can be done by editing connection in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/connection_name`

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/connection_name


[connection]
id=Auto XXXX
uuid=f4a27a71-202f-45ac-bc58-59a55600f515
type=802-11-wireless

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=XXXX
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=18:CF:5E:23:2A:0A
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
auth-alg=open
psk=yyyyyyyyy

[ipv4]
method=auto
routes1=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;32;yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy;0;

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - represent ip address of mail server

yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy - represent gateway foe wlan0 interface

Edit 1

Second method is more precise but also more complicated

Let’s start from the iptable. Here we shall take `smtp` as the service for routing. Use `mangle` table of iptable for modifying the `smtp` packets.

```
  sudo iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp –dport 993 -j MARK –set-mark 0×1
```

We are marking all packets with destination port `993` as ’0×1′ .

Now save and restart `iptables`.

```
service iptables save
service iptables restart
```

To delete this entry from `iptables` we can use `-D` instead of `-A`.

Next, create a new IP route table in `/etc/iproute2/rt_table` by just giving an entry

```
100 smtp
```

Write rule for `smtp` packets.

```
ip rule add fwmark 0×1 lookup smtp
```

Add route at new table smtp. Here we shall use ’192.168.1.1′ as the gateway for `smtp`. All other traffic will go through the
default gateway, which can be seen by IP route show command.

We copy all entries except default gateway entry from main table.

```
 sudo ip route show table main | grep -Ev ^default | while read ROUTE ; do ip route add table sshtable $ROUTE; done
```

Add default gateway entry for `smtp` packets to table `smtp`

```
  sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 table smtp
```

Use `ip route show table smtp to show all routes at`smtp`.

That’s it..we have done it!!!

Repeat everything for `imap` on port `465`.

Answer (score 0):

first, Make sure you have the `iproute` package installed. If you have the ip command then you're set

Edit `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables` and add a new table by appending the following line:

```
200 wlan-route
```

You then need to configure your new routing table named wlan-route with a default gateway and create rules to conditionally send traffic to that table. I'll assume your default gateway is 192.168.0.1. Naturally this needs to match your actual network, and not just my assumptions.

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table wlan-route
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table wlan-route
```

Your final annotated script would look like this:

```
# Populate secondary routing table
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0 table wlan-route
# Anything with this fwmark will use the secondary routing table
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table wlan-route
# Mark these packets so that iproute can route it through wlan-route
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 993 -j MARK --set-mark 1
# now rewrite the src-addr
iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o wlan0 -p tcp --dport 993 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.2
```

this script sends any traffic on port 993 via wlan0

[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21093/output-traffic-on-different-interfaces-based-on-destination-port)